# get checked and unchecked of checkbox in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, checked

If we have multiple checkbox in ng-repeat and i want to determine in which checkbox is checked or unchecked in controller's action. so i was not able to do it.

```
<ul class="list-month" id="divMonths">                           
    <li ng-repeat="m in model.Months">
        <div>                                               
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{m.Month}}" ng-model="$index"  class="left" ng-change="onClickMonth($index)" />                                                 
        </div>   
    </li>                                                                  
</ul>  


 $scope.onClickMonth = function (id) {        
        if (id=== true) {
            alert("true");
        }
        else {
            alert("false");
        }
    };>
```

Comment: You're comparing if id (which is given to your method by $index which is a integer) is true... That can only be false. Try to console log id (you'll probably see 0, 1, 2, 3). Now remove '=== true' in your condition, you should see your alert true

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the `multiple` option.

```
 <select multiple="multiple" ng-model="value" ng-options="m in model.Months"> </select>
```

`value` will then be an array that is filled as soon as a checkboxed is selected.